# ¿Cómo hacer un while si mysqli_fetch_array está en otro archivo?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Tengo 4 archivos, en los cuales al hacer click en un botón muestro todos los registros de archivos que cada usuario ha hecho, si le doy click al usuario 1 me muestra los registros de ese usuario, eso me funciona correctamente, el problema surge que solo me muestra el primer registro de cada usuario, sé que tengo que hacer un while, pero el problema es que el mysqli_fetch_array se encuentra en otro archivo. Espero y me puedan ayudar

En el archivo 1 llamado Gestor.php declaro la función obtenerArchivoUsuario()

```
    public function obtenerArchivoUsuario($idUsuario) {
     $conexion = Conectar::conexion();
        
         $sql = "SELECT id_archivo, id_usuario, nombre, tipo, ruta FROM archivos WHERE id_usuario = '$idUsuario'";
        
           $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
        
           $archivo = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    
           $datos = array(
            "idArchivo" => $archivo['id_archivo'],
            "idUsuario" => $archivo['id_usuario'],
            "Nombre" => $archivo['nombre'],
            "Tipo" => $archivo['tipo'],
            "Ruta" => $archivo['ruta']
                                        );
                    
           mysqli_close($conexion);
        
           return $datos;
                    
                    
     }
```

En el archivo 2 obtenerArchivoUsuario.php llamó a la función para mandar el array a un AJAX

```
         <?php 
        
           require_once "../../clases/Gestor.php";
        
           $archivosUsuario = new Gestor;
        
           echo json_encode($archivosUsuario->obtenerArchivoUsuario($_POST['idUsuario']));
        
        
         ?>
```

En el archivo 3 llamado Gestor.js obtengo el array para poder imprimirlos en un html

```
         function obtenerArchivosUsuario(idUsuario) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "idUsuario=" + idUsuario,
                url: "../procesos/gestor/obtenerArchivoUsuario.php",
                success:function(respuesta){
                respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
                            
                $('#id_Archivo').html(respuesta['idArchivo']);
                $('#id_Usuario').html(respuesta['idUsuario']);
                $('#nombreA').html(respuesta['Nombre']);
                $('#tipoA').html(respuesta['Tipo']);
                $('#rutaA').html(respuesta['Ruta']);
                          
            }
           });
          }
```

Por ultimo obtengo los datos en una tabla

```
    <tbody>
                            
    <tr>
        <td id="id_Archivo" hidden=""></td>
        <td id="id_Usuario" hidden=""></td>
        <td id="nombreA"></td>
        <td id="tipoA"></td>
        <td id="rutaA">
        <a href="" download="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
            <span class="fas fa-download"></span>
        </a>
        </td>
        </tr>
                        
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando con clases, debes usar herencia o inyección de dependencias para utilizar elementos de otras clases de esta manera puedes llamar los métodos de otras clases sin ningún problema.

si no estas usando POO, lo que debes hacer es poner el bucle en una función y llamarla desde el otro archivo, previas carga del primero con un include o require.